# CNAME to a wildcard subdomain

Tags: dns, subdomain, wildcard, cpanel, cname

Just trying to create an web application, clients can create their own instance of the app, so I created a wildcard subdomain in CPanel, checked VirtualHosts and the A record in the DNS, all fine.

Now when I go to "client1app.domain.tld" it works, takes me to the clients app, but when that client creates a cname "app.clientdomain.tld" to "client1app.domain.tld", I get redirected to cPanels "Default Web Site Page".

I double-checked everything.

App DNS:

```
*.domain.tld.   3600 IN A   x.x.x.x
```

Customer DNS

```
app.clientdomain.tld.   3600 IN CNAME   client1app.domain.tld
```

App VirtualHost:

```
ServerName  _wildcard_.domain.tld
ServerAlias *.domain.tld
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: I do have root, this is a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple things first, have you added *.domain.tld as a subdomain in cPanel using the user interface and not the command line?

I have tried to replicate this problem using one of my WHM servers and could not.

I recommend first updating cPanel/WHM to the latest version as some support articles covering wildcard subdomains point to some old versions of cPanel have bugs with wildcard subs which are now fixed.

I would also rebuild the httpd.conf if you have at any point manually edited it. Also make sure that the subdomain is not the same as the hostname as this causes some internal binding errors.

I set my environment up using only the cPanel sudomain button and not using the DNS editors in WHM or cPanel

Comment: Yes, a wildcard subdomain was created that pointed to the Application directory.